# How to transfer a JSON object into a Python object?

Tags: python, json

I use:

```
json_str = '{"name":"Saeron", "age":23, "score":100}'
def json2dict(d):
    return dict(d['name'],d['age'],d['score'])
d = json.loads(json_str, object_hook=json2dict)
print(d.name)
```

but get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/40471/PycharmProjects/untitled/untitled.py", line 693, in <module>
    d = json.loads(json_str, object_hook=json2dict)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\json\__init__.py", line 367, in loads
    return cls(**kw).decode(s)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
  File "C:/Users/40471/PycharmProjects/untitled/untitled.py", line 692, in json2dict
    return dict(d['name'],d['age'],d['score'])
TypeError: dict expected at most 1 arguments, got 3
```

I follow the steps which instructs to unpickle a Json obj to a Python obj, just like this:

```
json_str = '{"age": 20, "score": 88, "name": "Bob"}'
print(json.loads(json_str, object_hook=dict2student))
```

Why can't it take effect on a dict? How can I revise?

Comment: Remove the `object_hook`, you don't really need it.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `return dict(**d)`, but it is redundant because `json.loads` automatically converts your json to a dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you load json using `d = json.loads(json_str)` d is python dict
you cannot get the item using .(dot).

You need:

```
json_str = '{"name":"Saeron", "age":23, "score":100}'
d = json.loads(json_str)
print(d['name'])
```

Answer (score 2):

json.loads can evaluate your string as a Python dictionary directly as follows:

```
json_str = '{"name":"Saeron", "age":23, "score":100}'
d = json.loads(json_str)
print(d['name'])
>>>Saeron
```

The function you pass via the object_hook parameter will receive the dictionary that was created from the given string as input